# Retrieving data from unnormalized vertically ordered table

Tags: sql

I have the following relation:

```
employeevalue(id, name, value, code)

id      name        value       code

101     bobby       150         100
101     bobby       12          150
101     bobby       14.6        200
102     mary        189         100
102     mary        128         150
102     mary        112         200
103     john        112         100
103     john        13          150
103     john        76          200
```

Where code 100 is value1, 150 is value2 and 200 is value3. How could I write an SQL statement to retrieve the following from this table?

```
id      name        value1      value2      value3
101     bobby       150         12          14.6
102     mary        189         128         112
103     john        112         13          76
```

Comment: Some database engines allow pivot queries, but you didn't specify yours.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: sorry, im using oracle 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when code = 100 then value end) as value1,
       max(case when code = 150 then value end) as value2,
       max(case when code = 200 then value end) as value3
from table t
group by id;
```